# What means the gen2 in Ubuntu Server 22_04-lts-gen2?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, ubuntu-server

I am new to Azure VMs and want to have the latest Ubuntu Server stable LTS release. However the list of images isn't quite clear to me:

```
az vm image list -o table --all --publisher Canonical --offer Ubuntu --sku 22_04-lts --architecture x64
// ...
x64             0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy           Canonical    22_04-lts               Canonical:0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy:22_04-lts:22.04.202302280                22.04.202302280
x64             0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy           Canonical    22_04-lts-gen2          Canonical:0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy:22_04-lts-gen2:22.04.202204200           22.04.202204200
```

What is the difference between `22_04-lts` and `22_04-lts-gen2`? Is `22_04-lts-gen2` another word for version `22.04.2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gen 2 VMs have some improvements over the previous generations:

> Generation 2 VMs support key features that aren't supported in generation 1 VMs. These features include increased memory, Intel Software Guard Extensions (Intel SGX), and virtualized persistent memory (vPMEM). Generation 2 VMs running on-premises, have some features that aren't supported in Azure yet.
>
> Generation 2 VMs use the new UEFI-based boot architecture rather than the BIOS-based architecture used by generation 1 VMs. Compared to generation 1 VMs, generation 2 VMs might have improved boot and installation times.

([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/generation-2))